# How to check if a variable is NULL, then set it with a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL stored procedure where I find the max value from a table.

If there is no value I want to set the variable to yesterday's date.

```
DECLARE current_procedure_name CHAR(60) DEFAULT 'accounts_general';
DECLARE last_run_time datetime DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE current_run_time datetime DEFAULT NOW();

-- Define the last run time
SET last_run_time := (SELECT MAX(runtime) 
FROM dynamo.runtimes WHERE procedure_name = @current_procedure_name);

-- if there is no last run time found then use yesterday as starting point
IF(@last_run_time IS NULL) THEN
    SET last_run_time := DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END IF;

SELECT @last_run_time;
```

The problem is that `@last_run_time` is always NULL.

The following code is not being executed for some reason

```
IF(last_run_time IS NULL) THEN
    SET last_run_time := DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END IF;
```

How can I set the variable `@last_run_time` correctly?

Comment: I like to use `COALESCE` for replacing nulls. 

    COALESCE(@last_run_time, Date_Sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Thank you. Apparently the problem is that I am not using the variables correctly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`@last_run_time` is a [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and `last_run_time datetime` one [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html), are different variables.

Try: `SELECT last_run_time;`

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE current_procedure_name CHAR(60) DEFAULT 'accounts_general';
    DECLARE last_run_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE current_run_time DATETIME DEFAULT NOW();

    -- Define the last run time
    SET last_run_time := (SELECT MAX(runtime) FROM dynamo.runtimes WHERE procedure_name = current_procedure_name);

    -- if there is no last run time found then use yesterday as starting point
    IF(last_run_time IS NULL) THEN
        SET last_run_time := DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END IF;

    SELECT last_run_time;

    -- Insert variables in table2
    INSERT INTO table2 (col0, col1, col2) VALUES (current_procedure_name, last_run_time, current_run_time);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: then how can I make the first 3 variables Global? as I need to call them later in my code?

Comment: define them before calling the stored proc, so they have a scope outside the proc.

Comment: I need to define them in the procedure because I only need to use with within BEGIN....END. But need to know what is the correct way of using them.

Comment: I do not know you're trying to do and do not understand what you mean when you say you call them later in your code. The user-defined variables are session-specific, we can say that "global" to the session.

Comment: What I mean is that I want to define a variable on the top from a select statement. If there is noting found in the database then make that variable = yesterday. later I want to insert the value of those 3 variables into a different table. so How can I properly set the variable?  thanks

Comment: Everything within the stored procedure?

Comment: @wchiquito  yes everything in with int the procedure.

Comment: In that case, you do not need user-defined variables, keep all local variables in the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you please show me how? this is the first time I try to use variables. I never ever wrote a procedure in MySQL before

Comment: Update my answer with a small example.