# MySQL how to properly check a variable's value from SELECT INTO statement

Tags: mysql

I have a `before insert` trigger in a MySQL 8.0 database that checks for the incoming status and passes it along to the stored procedure, which then returns a value to be SET and passed along to be inserted. The stored procedure is being called correctly; however, when checking the entry in the database, the desired value of `1` is expected. However, `NULL` is there.

Here is the `BEFORE_INSERT` trigger on the table

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`` TRIGGER `data_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `data` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE newSearchAddressId INTEGER;

IF NEW.status = 'fresh' THEN
    CALL CALC_FRESH_SEARCH_ADDRESS_ID(NEW.lead, @newSearchAddressId);
    SET NEW.searchAddressId = @newSearchAddressId;
END IF;
END
```

Here is what's in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`` PROCEDURE `CALC_FRESH_SEARCH_ADDRESS_ID`(
    IN leadId INT,
    OUT newSearchAddressId INT
)
proc_label: BEGIN
    DECLARE lastSearchAddressID INT;
    DECLARE lastStatus VARCHAR(100);
    
    SELECT
        `searchAddressId`,
        `status`
    INTO
        lastSearchAddressID,
        lastStatus
    FROM `leads`
    WHERE `id` = leadId;
    
    -- if there is no status previous it's a first time entry
    IF lastStatus IS NULL THEN
        SET newSearchAddressId = 1;
        LEAVE proc_label;
    END IF;
END
```

In the `SELECT` statement above from `leads` table I am assured that only one row will be returned.

The desired outcome is that I select those two columns, `status` and `searchAddressId`, and if `status` is `NULL`, then we know that there is no previous entry and, therefore, a brand new record. Because it is a brand new record, we assign the `@newSearchAddressId` to the value of `1` and leave the stored procedure early.

I think I am incorrectly setting the variables or checking in the IF statement. That's at least what I think is going on. I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499747/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-null-then-set-it-with-a-mysql-stored-procedure) and tried setting just *one* variable to check with an IF statement but the same undesired result of `NULL` being in the database.

Here is sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `lead` INT NOT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `searchAddressId INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO `data` (`lead`, `status`, `searchAddressId`)
VALUES(1, 'fresh',     1),
VALUES(2, 'suspended', 1),
VALUES(3, 'stale',     1),
VALUES(4, 'fresh',     1),
VALUES(5, 'cancelled', 1);
```

Based on the data above, here is what I am expecting from the procedure above

```
DECLARE lastSearchAddressID INT;
DECLARE lastStatus VARCHAR(100);

SELECT `searchAddressId`, `status`
INTO lastSearchAddressID, lastStatus
FROM `data`
WHERE `lead` = 6;
```

based on the `SELECT` statement above `searchAddressID` and `lastStatus` should be NULL
so when reaching the `IF` statement of

```
    IF lastStatus IS NULL THEN
        SET newSearchAddressId = 1;
        LEAVE proc_label;
    END IF;
```

Integer `1` should be assigned to the `OUT newSearchAddressId INT` in the stored procedure's parameters.

A follow-up query of

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `lead` = 6;
```

Would yield:

| id | lead | status | searchAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 'fresh' | 1 |

What is yielded:

| id | lead | status | searchAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 'fresh' | NULL |

here is the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wo1UDg5L) the fiddle is not working but while I fiddle with getting it working I think you can see more clearly the expectations

Comment: you are confusing user defined variables and local variables @leadId is not the same as leadid

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks, so the issue is within the stored procedure and how I am using the local vs. user defined variables?

Comment: `DECLARE lastStatus VARCHAR(100);` is local variable. `@lastStatus` is user-defined variable. ANOTHER variable. Assigning the value to one of them does not alter the value of another variable. Recommendation - do not use UDV, use only LV.

Comment: ok @Akina thanks, I will look at it further, I have changed it to only use LV as per your suggestion however, entries in the column are still `null` so I'll keep investigating, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Provide some sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows), INSERT query and desired final data state.

Comment: @Akina I hope the data is sufficient.

Comment: *I hope the data is sufficient.* No. Your SP calls from `leads` table - you'd provide it too. PS. A fiddle with your data and code: https://dbfiddle.uk/QgQiWm4G You may edit/update it and provide the link.