# Filling up positions?

Tags: php, database, matching

```
UPDATE job_details 
    WHERE assigned AS +1 
    WHEN assigned is NULL 
    WHEN student_details.jobscope = job_details.jobscop 
    AND student_details.jobscope1 ='IT'
```

Is this query right? 
My motive is to get the assigned row in the database to (+1) each time a student is assigned to a job with a jobscope of IT.

Comment: Not in proper format. `SET` is the first thing that is missing

Comment: Try running the query on the database but rolling back the changes in order to prevent any issues. You can use SQL transactions for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051957/testing-mysql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE job_details 
JOIN student_details ON student_details.jobscope = job_details.jobscop
SET assigned = (assigned+1) 
WHERE  student_details.jobscope1 ='IT'
```

Comment: Also is there a field name with `jobscope1` or is it a mis-spelling

Comment: There is . thank you i have managed to solved it after using the SET function. Thank you!