# Determine affected TABLE and ROWs before executing a SQL in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to create a algorithm which will extract affected TABLE and ROWs from a DML SQL string, before executing it.

For example:

SQL :

```
update CUSTOMERS set NAME = 'XYZ' where age > 60;
```

I need to know the primary keys of affected records here.

In MS SQL Server

Comment: You can use transactions and rollback like this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011384/how-to-test-an-sql-update-statement-before-running-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011384/how-to-test-an-sql-update-statement-before-running-it)

Comment: In SQL Server you can output the data into a table variable. It's not affected by rollbacks so you can work with the data later. But, whatever you're asking is probably not what you want to do in reality. What is the real question here? Why do you need to know the primary keys of affected rows

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using - MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: Also, never store age. People become older every year, and your table data will soon become out-of-date.

Comment: Not possible: You have to execute the UPDATE to see what records have been affected. If you do it within a transaction, you could rollback. In PostgreSQL you can use `RETURNING` in in SQL Server `OUTPUT`.

Comment: In MS SQL Server @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server (not in MySQL) you can use the OUTPUT clause of any DML transaction.

In your case the SQL command will be :

```
update CUSTOMERS 
set NAME = 'XYZ' 
OUTPUT inserted.primary_key
where age > 60;
```

If the key is compound of only one PK column.

Comment: In-case of complex update SQL where multiple tables are joined, is there a way to OUTPUT table name which is getting updated? I am writing a dynamic function where user might use alias to update.

Comment: There is always only one table to be the target table of an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE...